# Can a VB.NET .dll assembly be reflected by C#

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, clr

I assume because the CLR this wouldn't be an issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.  Reflection is a CLR technology and works on any CLS compliant, and sometimes not so compliant, assembly no matter the language which created it.

Comment: You changed it just as I was commenting!

Answer (score 4):

.NET doesn't care what language the assembly was written in, so your C# application will have no problem using reflection with a VB.NET assembly.

Answer (score 3):

Any .NET language turns into IL bytecode when it's run through the compiler. Reflector and similar tools work by reverse-engineering the IL back into a higher-level syntax, but they don't necessarily produce the *precise* code that was compiled originally. They just provide you with a higher-level "approximation" which will compile into the same bytecode.

It's best to think of these tools as answering the question, "what could I have written to generate this result?" rather than, "what did the original author write to generate this result?"